# How to generate a password file to crack the zip file?

Tags: python, hash, zip

I have an assignment regarding zip file password cracking by using python. It is not an unethical or illegal cracking project, it is an school assignment. I would like to ask how to generate passwords and test for cracking one by one? i.e. firstly generating a password '0' and then test ingit, if it is not successfully cracked, it then will generates second a password '1' and test it again.

I had some code, but the problem is it only starts to crack the zip file after it generates a bunch of passwords. For example, I set it to generate starting from '0000' to '9999', when I run the code, it will generates all the passwords from '0000' to '9999', then it will just start to crack the zip file.

Here is my code:

```
import zipfile
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import product
import itertools  


str_09 = "0123456789"

file_pwd = 'password/pwd-str_09-8.txt'
mystring = str_09

myfile = open(file_pwd, 'w')
for a in range(1,6):
  for i in itertools.product(mystring, repeat=a):
    myfile.write("%s\n" % ''.join(map(str, i)))
myfile.close()

file_pwd = 'password/pwd-str_09-8.txt'
zip_file_created_a = 'file/a5.zip'

count = 1

with open(file_pwd,'rb') as text:
        for entry in text.readlines():
            password = entry.strip()
            try:
                with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_created_a,'r') as zf:
                    zf.extractall(pwd=password)
                    data = zf.namelist()[0]
                    data_size = zf.getinfo(data).file_size
                    print('''******************************\n[+] Password found! ~ %s\n ~%s\n ~%s\n******************************''' 
                        % (password.decode('utf8'), data, data_size))
                    break

            except:
                number = count
                print('[%s] [-] Password failed! - %s' % (number,password.decode('utf8')))
                count += 1
                pass
```

Comment: I'm on my phone and can't type up an answer, but one way to solve this would be by replacing `text.readlines()` with a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: Hi @AndrewF How to replace the ``text.readlines()`` with generator function? I had gone through the generator function but still can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the request, but one thing you can do, as commented by another, is use a generator. First, you don't need to generate a password file, you can test each password when generating it. To do this, you can yield from a generator. Adapting your code, we have:

```
  1 import itertools                                                               
  2                                                                                
  3 def password_generator(min_length=1, max_length=6, chars='123456789'):         
  4     for i in range(min_length, max_length):                                    
  5         for password in itertools.product(chars, repeat=i):                    
  6             yield ''.join(password)                                            
  7                                                                                
  8 # Showing a sample of passowrds.                                               
  9 for _, password in zip(range(100), password_generator()):                      
 10     print(password)                                                            
 11                                                                                
 12 is_successful_extraction = False                                               
 13                                                                                
 14 for password in password_generator():                                          
 15     try:                                                                       
 16         with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_created_a,'r') as zf:
 17             zf.extractall(pwd=password)
 18             data = zf.namelist()[0]
 19             data_size = zf.getinfo(data).file_size
 20         print('[+] Extracted - password: {}'.format(password))                 
 21         is_successful_extraction = True                                        
 22         break                                                                  
 23     except RuntimeError:                                                       
 24         print('[-] Failure to extract - password: {}'.format(password))        
 25                                                                                
 26 if is_successful_extraction:                                                   
 27     print('[+] Successful extraction')                                         
 28 else:                                                                          
 29     print('[!] No extraction complete')
```

This is helpful for many reasons. First, the generator has parameters, so you can tweak the length of passwords to generate. Next, you don't have to store all of the passwords in memory, or on disk. Should be a bit faster. Note that `readlines` stores the contents of the file in RAM. Last, you only iterate over the passwords once - that is when generating them.

For more information on generators, see this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generators-in-python/).

Comment: Hi @DasHund Thanks for your answer!! Really appreciate!! May I know what codes need to put on part within ``# Run your extraction here. If it fails, it will throw a runtime error. See the source for additional details.`` this comment?

Comment: Updated and put your code in it. Worth noting, didn't try to run it.

Comment: I tried to insert these codes ``z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"C:/Users/tcc/Desktop/zip file cracker/input/a2.zip", 'r')`` ``z.extractall(r"C:/Users/tcc/Desktop/zip file cracker/output", pwd=password.encode())`` ``z.close`` within that comment part, it successfully cracks the zip file, but the weird thing is, it can only crack 2 digits of password like '00', if more the password more than 2 digits like '000', it will shows ``zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid code lengths set``, I don't understand what is the problem, anything wrong with my codes?